# for loop in python to get nth element in a query set

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Please can you check my python code below if it okay to do this for a queryset :

```
gp_id= [0,1,2]
for gp in gp_id:
    specail_list = Special.objects.filter(
        promotion=False, 
        start__lte=date_instance, 
        minimum_stay__lte=nights, 
        object_id=room_filter.id, 
        end__gte=date_instance, 
        is_active=True, 
        member_deal=False
    )[gp]
    print specail_list
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the queryset?

Comment: i am trying to get what is returned if add 0 on the [] or 1 or 2

Comment: Still not clear what is the aim of this code.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are trying to ask for the first three elements in the list, indexes 0, 1, 2. So while what you are doing is valid, this way is better.

**Slice** - common function each python programmer should know:

**Python Docs for "Slice:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

**Django Docs for "Limiting Querysets":** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Will grab first three elements starting on the not entered 0th index. The brackets could have also been `[0:3]`.

```
special_list = Special.objects.filter(
    promotion=False, 
    start__lte=date_instance, 
    minimum_stay__lte=nights, 
    object_id=room_filter.id, 
    end__gte=date_instance, 
    is_active=True, 
    member_deal=False
)[:3]
```

Comment: thanks yes i have already tried that but it did not work on my entire code

Comment: Maybe edit your question to show examples of where it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop though like this:

```
special_queryset = Special.objects.filter(
    promotion=False, 
    start__lte=date_instance, 
    minimum_stay__lte=nights, 
    object_id=room_filter.id, 
    end__gte=date_instance, 
    is_active=True, 
    member_deal=False
    id__in = gp_id
)
for i in special_queryset:
    print(i)
```

If you want to update the same thing for the items in the queryset, then use `update()` method.

```
special_queryset.update(promotion=True)
```